# android keyboard inputtype=number parentheses doens't work

Tags: android, keyboard, numbers, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I'he got problem with keyboard in my Android app. All I want is numeric pad with '+', '-', '*', '/', '(', ')', '.' keys. Problem is that

```
android:inputtype="number"
```

gives me only few of them and they aren't working, just numbers works.
I've tried combinations number|phone and others but nothing is satisfying. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can't force that, the system isn't set up that way.  The keyboard is a separate app, and isn't even the same between manufacturers stock, and many people download new ones (Swype, Swiftkey, etc).  The keyboard itself gets to decide what it displays for each input type, and they all decide on their own.  There's no way to force them to display certain keys or not to display certain keys.  Even if you find an answer for 1 keyboard, there's no guarantee it works on any other.

If you absolutely need this (I assume you're writing a calculator), write your own keyboard or fake a keyboard using buttons.

Comment: I understand that. Displayed keyboard doesn't have to have only that keys I've mention. The point is, when I go to EditText I want quick access to numers and that +-*... keys. It could have any other keys but also that few which I want. So, if you say so, my second question is, why, when I use inputtype=number, there are e.g. '(',')' symbols but they doesn't work?